# vs2008 failed to capture exceptions with SetUnhandledExceptionFilter

Tags: c++, exception, crt

I'm writing a CrashReport.dll that can be used by any exe, as long as the exe load it, it captures all exceptions, prompt user to report, restart the application, etc. 
I'm using the **SetUnhandledExceptionFilter**, but it's not working. Seems that the VS2008 CRT is always handling the crash, when there's a crash, it popups a dialog with "Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library", my exception callback is not called.

I googled a lot, articles say that the CRT registers a exception handler. But when I debug my exe with OllyDbg, set a break point at **SetUnhandledExceptionFilter**, I found it is called twice.
the first is in CRTStartup, it's before main
the second is in the main function, called by my code
there's no more call to it, and I even set an API hook to **SetUnhandledExceptionFilter** to prevent further calling.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: "It pops up a dialog..." What is the stack trace at this point?  What is the full text of the dialog?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233255/how-does-setunhandledexceptionfilter-work-in-net-winforms-applications

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems has something to do with the project configuration, I deleted the old solution, created a new and copy all the files to the new solution, it works. I don't know why.
But thanks guys.